# Python quickfix: ordering of groups in MarketDataRequest

Tags: python, quickfix

I'm using python lib quickfix and struggled with MarketDataRequest

MarketDataRequest is:

```
toApp: 8=FIXT.1.1|9=145|35=V|34=3|49=COMPANY|52=20210629-11:55:06.807|56=EXCHANGE|1128=8|146=1|55=DANGCEMU1|262=91a7c90b-fcb2-40ce-82f8-5ed0819c8132|263=0|264=1|267=1|269=0|10=185
```

Response from server :

```
 fromAdmin: 8=FIXT.1.1|9=127|35=3|34=2|49=EXCHANGE|52=20210629-11:55:06.894|56=COMPANY|45=2|58=Incorrect number in group count for tag 146|371=146|372=V|373=16|10=122
```

I guess the problem is in wrong ordering of groups in request:
tags 146=1|55=DANGCEMU1 goes before 267=1|269=0

**Upd:**
But in DataDictionary groups order is right. I checked different settings by changing groups order in FIX50SP1.xml but nothing changed.

How I prepared message:

```
import quicfix as fix
import quickfix50sp1

mes = quickfix50sp1.MarketDataRequest()
mes.setField(fix.MDReqID(str(uuid.uuid4())))
mes.setField(fix.SubscriptionRequestType("0"))

mes.setField(fix.MarketDepth(1))


group_md = quickfix50sp1.MarketDataRequest().NoMDEntryTypes() # MDReqGrp
group_md.setField(fix.MDEntryType("0"))  # Top of book
mes.addGroup(group_md)



group_sym = quickfix50sp1.MarketDataRequest().NoRelatedSym() # InstrmtMDReqGrp
group_sym.setField(fix.Symbol("DANGCEMU1"))
mes.addGroup(group_sym)
```

Configuration file:

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
LogonTimeout=10
ReconnectInterval=25
FileLogPath=./Logs/
FileStorePath=./Sessions
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=Y
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
CheckLatency=N
PossResend=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=N
ResetOnError=Y
MaxLatency=5
PreserveMessageFieldsOrder=Y
Username=USERNAME
SenderCompID=COMPANY
Password=password
TransportDataDictionary=fix/FIXT11.xml
AppDataDictionary=fix/FIX50SP1.xml

[SESSION]
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP1
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
TargetCompID=EXCHANGE
HeartBtInt=30
EncryptMethod=0
SocketConnectHost=IP_adress
SocketConnectPort=Port
```

MarketDataRequest from fix/FIX50SP1.xml file:

```
  <message name='MarketDataRequest' msgtype='V' msgcat='app'>
   <field name='MDReqID' required='Y' />
   <field name='SubscriptionRequestType' required='Y' />
   <component name='Parties' required='N' />
   <field name='MarketDepth' required='Y' />
   <field name='MDUpdateType' required='N' />
   <field name='AggregatedBook' required='N' />
   <field name='OpenCloseSettlFlag' required='N' />
   <field name='Scope' required='N' />
   <field name='MDImplicitDelete' required='N' />
   <component name='MDReqGrp' required='Y' />
   <component name='InstrmtMDReqGrp' required='Y' />
   <component name='TrdgSesGrp' required='N' />
   <field name='ApplQueueAction' required='N' />
   <field name='ApplQueueMax' required='N' />
   <field name='MDQuoteType' required='N' />
  </message>
```

In DataDictionary file order is right MDReqGrp(tags 267=1|269=0) goes before InstrmtMDReqGrp(tags46=1|55=DANGCEMU1).
It's looks like I have an issue with DataDictionary. May be I missed some thin in message creation stage?

Comment: I think you should ask your counter party what they think the problem is. Are you sure they are using the plain vanilla DataDictionary? As soon as you keep the order inside the repeating group correct there should be no problem when the order of different repeating groups inside the message is different. BTW, the order of the tags/groups is defined at compile time, so if you wanted to change that order you needed to rebuild QuickFIX.

Comment: @ChristophJohn Thank you for your answer.  But in config exists one setting its called "PreserveMessageFieldsOrder" with description " Should the order of fields in the main outgoing message body be preserved or not (as defined in the configuration file). Default: only groups specified order is preserved." This option is "Y" in my config.

Comment: But even if I shuffle all tags in MarketDataRequest  which is from fix/FIX50SP1.xml file - order of tags in messages always the same. I checked is this xml file is loaded. It's looks like it's not applied? or I have misunderstanding with description? Description of "PreserveMessageFieldsOrder" setting here http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html

Comment: To be honest I am not that familiar with QuickFIX (more with QuickFIX/J which does not have that setting `PreserveMessageFieldsOrder`). However, how does your message look like when you set it to `N`? In general I think your message looks good. Did you try to ask your counter-party where they see the problem?